# How to configure jmf in net beans

Tags: java, netbeans, jmf

I am doing video capturing through webcam using jmf. i am very new to this and dont know how to use jmf.

I downloaded and installed jmf,it detects my video devise but now i want to run java code to detect the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the jar files of JMF ,and add these jar at the library .Here is the Link of example code for detecting the webcam using java code :

[Click Here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=28&threadID=5365494)

Please Check this, it works.I have tried this example it is very good.

Comment: i added the jar files but still my code is not working. is the link provided by u captures video & stores on a hard drive? please help.

Comment: It is detecting the web cam and running well also with laptop.I do not tested it to store video. I think this will works well.Try this.

Comment: Hello! this works,it detects web cam and plays the video. Can you help me with storing part? How will i use DataSink in that code.Please Help!